# Node-red - writing conditional function

Tags: node-red

What is wrong with this function?

```
if (msg.payload == “high”) {
    return [ msg, null, null ];
}

else if (msg.payload == “med”) {
    return [ null, msg, null ];
}

else { 
    return [null, null, msg];
}
```

I am receiving

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I am coding in node-red and wanted to create and return multiple messages in a function, to read one msg.payload and send it to 3 different outputs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a verbatim copy and paste it will be the opening and closing quotes for the string literals

Your code has  “ arround the strings instead of " which should be used.